# Can a "hero" player voluntarily become a traitor?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Can a player who is supposed to be a hero character become a traitor by their own will? For example: if the haunt doesn't specify any hidden traitors or others but  the hero character wants to help the monster any way is that allowed?

Comment: Aside from a player just doing this for kicks and giggles, is there some reason why a "hero" player would actually want to help the monster?

Answer (score 7):

No, a hero cannot become a traitor unless the rules of the scenario cause him to become one.

Allowing that would be no different than allowing a traitor to simply declare "I am a hero". Now, technically a hero can help the traitor if he wants to in a number of ways; but if the traitor wins that player would still lose.